# How to fix state updating in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using `little state machine` for the state management.  I have following state

```
export const todoState = { todoList: []  }
```

Now I am calling this using the actions where action is like

```
export const updateTodoList = (state, payload) => {
    return {
        ...state,
        toDoList: {
            ...state.toDoList,
            ...payload
        }
    }
}
```

calling this action

```
 updateToDoList({ id: '1', text:'11', isComplete: 'false })
```

But still actions does not update the array of toDoList and also it does not take the previous values into consideration .

Can any one help me with the actions updation code ? Thanks.

Comment: TYPO, `toDoList` vs `todoList`. You are declaring state as `todoList` and updaing property as `toDoList`

Comment: Yes that is but in the actions logic , is there any issue ?

Comment: `todoList` is an array not an object

Comment: Yes it is if I removed the  { } from there then it says  react-dom.development.js:4091 Uncaught TypeError: payload is not iterable

Comment: What does the state object look like in the action function? `console.log(state)` before the return statement. Knowing the exact structure of the object is key to how you can manipulate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** TYPO: `todoList` instead of `toDoList`

**2)** `todoList` is an array not an object. So spread it into an array.

**3)** Since you are passing an object so no need to spread it

```
export const updateTodoList = (state, payload) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    todoList: [
      ...state.todoList,
      payload,        // It will add the payload object into todoList
    ],
  };
};
```

Comment: Hey @decpk Thanks for this. Not sure why this says now  state.todoList is not iterable

Comment: just wanted to update that I have declared the state like

export const todoList = {
    todoList: []
}